# Read CSV records while ignoring trailing spaces

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm iterating through a csv file and pulling out data by the headers. But I want to allow for trailing spaces and still recognize the header.

For example `Header1,Header2,Header3` should still recognized as `Header1  ,Header2,Header3`

My code...

```
final Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csv));

for (CSVRecord record : CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().parse(in)) {
    try {
        final MyObject mo = new MyObject();
        mo.setHeader1(record.get("Header1"));
        mo.setHeader2(record.get("Header2"));
        mo.setHeader3(record.get("Header3"));
        ....
    }catch(){
       .... 
    }
}
```

But this of course will only find `Header1` if it matches exactly (no trailing spaces).

I couldn't find any method like `record.getIgnoreSpace()` or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the `CSVParser` object constructed using `CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().parse(in)` into a variable, then you can use the method `getHeaderMap()` to find the indices of the desired headers. These indices can then be used instead of the header names to look up the fields (which is actually also a more efficient way to perform the lookups).

One way to do it is like this:

```
CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().parse(in);
Map<String, Integer> headerMap = parser.getHeaderMap();

int header1Index = -1;
int header2Index = -1;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : headerMap.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    int index = entry.getValue();

    switch (name.trim()) {
    case "Header1":
        header1Index = index;
        break;
    case "Header2":
        header2Index = index;
        break;
    }
}

for (CSVRecord record : parser) {
    ...
    mo.setHeader1(record.get(header1Index));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below function can work as record.getIgnoreSpace():

> getRecordTrimmedLookup(headerMap, csvRecord, "Header1");

```
try(Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile)));  
                CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                        .withIgnoreEmptyLines() //Not Mandatory
                        .withIgnoreHeaderCase() //Not Mandatory
                        .withFirstRecordAsHeader() //Not Mandatory
                        .withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces());) //Not Mandatory
{
     Map<String, Integer> headerMap = parser.getHeaderMap();
     System.out.println(getRecordTrimmedLookup(headerMap, csvRecord, "Header1"));
}
```

getRecordTrimmedLookup can be defined as:

```
private String getRecordTrimmedLookup(Map<String, Integer> headerMap, CSVRecord csvRecord, String columnName) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : headerMap.entrySet())
        {
            String name = entry.getKey();
            int index = entry.getValue();
            if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(name), StringUtils.trimToEmpty(columnName)))
            {
                return csvRecord.get(index);
            }
        }
        return csvRecord.get(columnName);
    }
```

Note: StringUtils is a org.apache.commons:commons-lang3 library found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3).
Hope this answer helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to ignore the space in the header name (in between) using the following code - by using the get(index) instead of get("header_name"). And also, stop reading the csv when blank value/row is detected:

```
 CSVParser csvParser = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(br);
             for (CSVRecord record : csvParser) {
                 String number= record.get(0);
                 String date = record.get("date");
                 String location = record.get("Location");
                 String lsFile = record.get(3);
                 String docName = record.get(4);
              
                 
                 if(StringUtils.isEmpty(lsFile)) {
                     break;
                 }
          }
```

Comment: Hey, How did you get this working, CSVFormat.EXCEL is not working for me. Checkout this question I posted 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67964627/how-to-read-excel-xlsx-multipartfile-using-apache-csv-parser-current-approac

Comment: I think Apache commons CSV 1.8 API should work. It should have this --> CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse

Comment: It didn't work. I was under the wrong assumption. Basically CSVFormat.EXCEL is to be used when your .csv file is stored as excel. If you want to parse an excel file (.xslx or .xls) you need to use another suitable library. Thanks for taking out time for this